# Can I use HL2 Assets in my free Godot game?

Tags: copyright

I couldn't find some good textures for my Godot game, so I am  looking forward using Half-Life 2 assets. I have HL2 in my library on Steam.

Can I use those assets in my game?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is protected by copyright. The way games like Garry's mod get over this is by requiring you to have the game to use the assets